# Criando e verificando sessão - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Boa Noite galera, eu sou novo usando Laravel e estava criando algo básico de produtos, e estou com dúvidas em relação ao uso de sessão em laravel. Após o usuário fazer o login, como eu posso criar a sessão para ele, usar os dados dele em outras páginas. Além disso, como eu poderia fazer para verificar em cada página, se existe uma sessão ou não.
Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O laravel oferece uma maneira prática de criar toda a base de autenticação, através do seguinte comando:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Se você deseja fazer essa autenticação manual, na função que você deseja autenticar insira o seguinte código:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

//

public function login(Request $request){
  $credenciais = $request->only('email', 'password');

  if (Auth::attempt($credenciais)) {
    // após autenticar o usuário
  }
}
```

Para verificar se o usuário está logado utilize a seguinte função

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

Você também pode verificar se o usuário está autenticado através de middleware no arquivo de rotas

```
Route::get('perfil', function () {
    // usuário autenticado
})->middleware('auth.basic');
```

ou

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
   Route::get('perfil', function () {
    // usuário autenticado
   });
});
```

Você pode acessar a documentação do laravel na sessão Authentication, para fazer qualquer tipo de variação.

Comment: Assim não teria problema eu nao meio do projeto usar este comando? É um trabalho que estou fazendo pra facul.

Comment: Seria possivel fazer sem este comando make::auth?

Comment: Teria Joao, vou colocar um exemplo.

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo de como autenticar manualmente

Comment: No caso 'email' e 'senha' seriam os campos do form?

Comment: Isso joao, são os campos

Comment: E no caso de eu querer pegar o id do usuário que está logado para inserir em outra tabela.E como seria em relação a sessão?

Comment: Insira o id do usuário dentro das credenciais, antes de utilizar o `Auth::attempt($credenciais)`

Comment: No caso funcionou o login manual, mas eu preciso inserir nas views alguma coisa?

Comment: Através de um middleware você valida as rotas sem de fato precisar colocar na tela.

Comment: É pq eu consigo acessar outras páginas sem estar logado

Comment: Aonde eu insiro o middleware?

Comment: Arquivo de rotas